# Show SoftKeyboard in landscape but not entire screen

Tags: android, keyboard, landscape, android-softkeyboard

Im trying to achieve something like this image:
[image]

the problem its when im on landscape and put a searchbar like the image, the soft keyboard cover all screen,and i want the behavior like the image i tried

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

and seems isnt working,at least on jelly bean. any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i found the solution, in imeOptions of EditText, so i used

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
```

so the screen now its in middle :)

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txt_search"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoFullscreen"
    android:hint="@string/hint_search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Comment: To set it programmatically: `editText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_FULLSCREEN);`

Comment: I use "flagNoExtractUi" instead, and it also works. What's the difference between them exactly ?