# Edittext Click softinputadjustpan not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

I have some Android devices wherein I have one `EditText` on one screen in landscape mode. When I type characters upto some limit in the `EditText` the `softinput` `adjustpan` seems to work fine on Moto G Play when keyboard gains focus. But when I exceed those characters the screen looses the `softinput` `adjustpan` while gaining focus the next time.

**Please Note:** There is no maximum character limit. This works fine on rest of the devices.

I have SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN property set already.

Here are couple of screenshots. This is what is expected.

[image: screenshot1]

This one is the issue found on `Moto` G Play.

[image: screenshot2]

As you can see in the second image the layout containing `EditText` and send button is missing.

Comment: Your solution may here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277177/show-softkeyboard-in-landscape-but-not-entire-screen 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854029/androidwindowsoftinputmode-adjustpan-is-not-working

Comment: Have tried both the solutions already but they didn't work out. And moreover my code works on rest of the devices which include Samsung, MotoG5 and OnePlus as well.